# Date.ToString CulturalInfo doesn't work on some machines

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, format, tostring

I just started working with Arabic calendar and stumbled upon a problem.

I use this line to get the specific format of the string.

`.ToString("d MMMM yyyy, H:mm", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(locale))`

and on my dev machine, **everything works fine!**

[image]

but when I deploy it to a production server (virtual machine), something goes wrong and I get this:[image]

it means the code is the same, something goes wrong with my virtual machine.

What might it be? language packages or ... how can I fix it?

Comment: Because the culture of those machines might be different from the development machine, that is likely the cause.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your VM but you have set functionality to work with different culture

Comment: Well seems a lot a pic that I've read on xkcd time ago. Never mind: the problem is that, probably, the virtual machine has a different Culture Info and you get a different conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that I have experienced before.

It is likely a result of the culture/region settings on your VM being different from your development system.

If you make sure that these are the same, your problem should resolve itself, or you can hardcode which culture you would like to use.